# How to I make my folding panels work by using local space

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, transforms, constraints

I have made and rigged (using constraints) these folding panels for my model based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SGBf__4kDY
[image]

[image]

But since the Target and Origin are World Space, the Panels become wonky when I change the rotation of the model
[image]

So I changed the Target and Origin to Local Space on a single panel for testing
[image]

But when I try to fold it, the panel I set to local space refuses to fold
[image]

Is there a way for the panels to fold like in the world space example without becoming wonky when I turn them

Comment: you can try this tutorial here (it is a step by step tutorial, it's rigged and so rotation won't be a problem): https://youtu.be/07e1NUjYY_8

Answer (score 1):

## Use an outer source of transform

First of all made a root which will be used to rotate the construction: first item is parented to cube, you can replace it by empty.

[image]

Then add empty to control the rotation. Add copy rotation to the first joint and set up like this. Target is *empty*, in *world space*, Owner - *local space*.

[image]

Second joint: Note, that second copy rotation is used, with *mix* "*add*". Z inverted.

[image]

3rd joint the same but without inversion:

[image]

[image]

Repeat 2 and 3 for other joints

## Second variant - use drivers:

Click on z value of rotation from context menu and select "*copy as new driver*":

[image]

Then select second joint and on z value of rotation from context menu select "*Paste driver*", field will be purple:

[image]

Then from context menu select *edit driver*, *type* is *scripted expression*, *Expression* set as `rotation_euler * -2`:

[image]

Same for the 3rd, but remove minus from *expression* `rotation_euler * 2`

[image]

Repeat 2 and 3 for other joints